# Replace space with hyphen in link

Tags: php, string, wordpress

```
         <a href="/quote/tag/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_customauthor2', true); ?>">My Link></a>
```

I got this piece of code that echos 'user_submit_customauthor2' into an url. The problem is that it replaces space with %20 and I'd like it to replace it with a hyphen '-' instead.

I have searched an found this piece of code

```
         $string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
```

But I couldn't find anything that tells me how I'm supposed to insert it. Do I make it a function and call it? Is there a way to place it inline with the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you want:

```
<a href="/quote/tag/<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_customauthor2', true)); ?>">My Link></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_submit_customauthor2', true);
string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
echo '<a href="/quote/tag/'.$string.'">My Link></a>';
```

Comment: you have it backwards, he had it right: from php.net: `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Comment: So that will search for a `-`, replace with a space, within $string.  That is how he had it, I simply copied it and told him. I did not change mine.

Comment: I must have read the question after he changed it to the proper order. Had you provided the code he needed instead of just pasting his error in an answer, it probably would have been accepted. I saw your answer and was just totally confused. For people who come here in the future it is best that they chose my answer. I would actually edit your answer to be correct code. While it is more verbose than my answer, it would be working code that could be useful to others in a different circumstance. Stack overflow answers are useful for future google searches as much as for the OP.